# How do I aggregate data across multiple worksheets in excel?

Tags: excel

I've been trying to figure this out for some time now. We utilize the same evaluation through survey monkey for every one of our training sessions. There are 8 questions in total. For a single survey, we get the results back in an excel format with the data spread across 8 separate work sheets. What I would like to have is a formula that can be used to aggregate the data for each one of the questions across multiple spreadsheets.

For example, we want to know the average response for Question #1 from the training sessions for client ABC, DEF and HIJ. Hope that makes sense.

[Question 1](http://www.supermotors.net/getfile/987439/fullsize/question-1.jpg)

[Question 2](http://www.supermotors.net/getfile/987441/fullsize/question2.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you've been trying to figure it out for some time, undoubtedly you have tried some things. Describe what you have tried and why these approach(es) were inadequate.

Comment: I've been trying to manually do it which was much too time consuming. First I would open up the various instances of the spreadsheets, then copy the data from all of the all of the same questions and put it in a new spreadsheet. Honestly I gave up at that point.

Comment: In general, a tall skinny table is preferable to having related info in multiple sheets.  There are a whole lot of excel tools (Pivot Tables in particular) that can answer questions like you describe once you get the architecture right. Often times, you've got to manually add a column or two (like source or Client). It's a simple one-time process to copy the data, and then you've got simpler formulas and the ability to answer any question that comes up.

Comment: Didn't see your comment before now, that is helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something as simple as:

```
=SUM('Question 1:Question 8'!A1)
```

where A1 is the cell of interest on each sheet?

If you can put whatever result you want per question in the same cell on each sheet of the workbooks, you can use SUM over the range of sheets.

Comment: Want to try this a different way. I took the data/responses from each eval and put them into a single spreadsheet. Then I created a master spreadsheet call aggregate evals (see the image). Now I want to take all of the data from the subsequent evals and carry it over into the corresponding cells on my aggregate spreadsheet. (http://www.supermotors.net/getfile/987479/fullsize/eval.jpg)